# Banner Management System using Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, banner

I want to create an open source banner/advertising management app using Rails. The app is like the simplified version of OpenX, where user can define the ad zone, upload banner, and paste the javascripts on the page to view the ads.

This will be my first open source project and using this opportunity to learn Rails. But I searched around and seemed there are no similar apps or tutorials or solution, especially on **displaying the banner using javascripts on external websites**.

Any experts care to point me into the right direction? (which plugin/gems/js library to use, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  It would be better to dig into the project, and start asking specific questions as they come up.

Also, if this is your first rails app, you'll be much better off picking a simpler problem to solve, even if it's not a marketable product.  Trying to build something like this with no rails experience would be a recipe for frustration.

I'm not trying to hamper a new developer at all.  In fact, I try to give new rails developers all the help I can on my blog.  The best I can do is point you to my list of resources for [getting started with rails](http://kconrails.com/getting-started-with-ruby-on-rails/).  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I guessed you are right. But one last question (which relates to my above question), specifically: what is the best way to display the banner on an external website?